# Supremum of bounded family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{F}$ family of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded above in $X$, then $\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} f(x)<\infty$.
So far, I read in some books, definition of a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded above in $X$ if for each $x\in X$, there exists $K_x>0$ such that $f(x)\leq K_x$ for all $f\in \mathcal{F}$. 
My question: Why is $\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} f(x)<\infty$? 
Because when I have a family of functions $\mathcal{F}=\{f_n:X\to \mathbb{R}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ which is defined by $f_n(x)=n$ for all $x\in X$, then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is bounded above because for each $x\in X$, there exists $K_x=n+1$ such that $f_n(x)=n\leq n+1$. But, $\sup_{f_n\in \mathcal{F}} f_n(x)=\infty$.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The bound you give ($K_x = n+1$) doesn't apply to your whole family $\mathcal{F}$; it only applies to $f_k$ for $k \leq n$, so you don't meet the conditions to apply the claim about the supremum.

Comment: Your family of functions  $\{f_n \, |\,  n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is **not** bounded above: $sup_n f_n(x) = sup_n n$.

Comment: @tyo So, to say that $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded above, I should have the bound which can be applied to the whole family $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @BrianO Then, although for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is bounded above, that's not imply $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ bounded above, right?

Comment: @user136524 yes, exactly. However, it's also important to note that that while the bound has to apply to the entire family, it can be different at every point in the domain.

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's an understandable but critical confusion happening here. Let's look carefully at the boundedness condition you would like to apply:

> A family $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded above in $X$ if, *for each $x \in X$*, there exists $K_x > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq K_x$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

Notice, in particular, that the bounding constant $K_x$ *is* allowed to depend on $x$, but it *is not* allowed to depend on which $f \in \mathcal{F}$ you're looking at.

Here's an example to consider: define $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ f_n(x) = x + \frac{1}{n} $$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and set $\mathcal{F} = \{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then $K_x = x+1$ satisfies $f_n(x) \leq K_x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies the "bounded in $X$" condition you specified (with $X = \mathbb{R}$). There are two things I'd like to point out here: first, our bound $K_x$ does not depend on our choice of $n$; second, each function $f_n \in \mathcal{F}$ is unbounded over its whole domain. Nonetheless, we happily satisfy our boundedness condition because at any point $x$ we might pick, we can easily find a number bounding $f_n(x)$ for all $n$.

The takeaway is that (perhaps counterintuitively) the "$\mathcal{F}$ is bounded above in $X$" condition is less concerned with the boundedness of any particular function over the entirety of $X$ than it is with how the *entire family* of functions behave, compared to one another, *at a single point*. Hope that helps!